# Maximilian’s Earthen Grasp movement

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The hand rises from the ground upon casting the spell.

Is the hand attached to the ground?

Is the hand floating?

As an action, you can cause the hand to reach for a different creature or to move to a different unoccupied space within range.

Can the hand go 30 ft upward into the air?

There are three other hand spells and they all float/fly... I made a spell caster that has mage hand out almost all the time except when I need to concentrate.  The hand has a “mind of its own” in some regard, in game, and is named and interacted with by players and NPCs.  Therefore, I wanted to use Chill Touch, Max’s Earthen Grasp, and Bigby’s Hand all as situational Magical upgrades to the named hand character.   Wondering if Max’s Grasp doesn’t allow me to send the hand into the air against flyin creatures